# PHP JQuery JavaScript - TreeView with checkbox toggle

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, treeview

Is there a plugin or snippet that can help me achieve this?

[image]

I don't mind developing it from scratch but I wouldn't mind saving some time to build off something. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out

http://www.treeview.net/treemenu/3fr_checkbox.html

http://www.treeview.net/tv/download.asp <- Indirect download link for said library.

Comment: Thanks, looks like the tree view functionality is messy but I need it.